# Call clean of WebRTC call in callkit iOS

Tags: ios, webrtc, callkit

I'm integrating callkit with my voip ios application. The call is initially answered in callkit and the app is invoked. While I end the call I'm 
 executing CXEndCallAction on CXController and I simultaneously clean up the webrtc peerconnection. During this the call screen is dismissed and a green bar flashes on top of the screen, which actually takes my tab bar below my whole tab bar. I'm stuck with this from the whole week. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [provider reportCallWithUUID:yourCallUUID endedAtDate:[NSDate date] reason:CXCallEndedReasonRemoteEnded]; to end the call.